# Rails modelling has_one filtered by another foreign_key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I'm trying to model to get the user's current company role through associations in rail.

A user can have many companies and different status in each company.

How do I model so I can do something like `User.first.current_company.status`

I already have the User and Company tables.

**In another words:**

A has_many Bs

A has_many Cs

A has_one B through C

(There are many As that has_one B through C)

How to define this association?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I created a join table which belonged to all the different entities (A, B, C).

A can has_many B through that join table
B can has_many C through that join table
C can has_many A through that join table

A, B and C has_many of that join table

To get a B or C of A, I create a method to retrieve the record from the join table with A.
Then use that record to return B or C.

Answer (score 1):

Given the following model schemas:

```
# app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :companies
end

# app/models/company.rb
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_one :status
end

# app/models/status.rb
class Status < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company
end
```

The following relationships are valid:

```
status = Status.first
company = Company.first
user = User.first

company.status = status # Assign status to company

user.companies << company # Add company to user

user.companies.last.status == Status.first # Status of user's last company is the original status
#=> true
```

Comment: This is assuming the Status need to have company_id. What if the Status just needs to have status (id, status) without company data and there is a join table to join User, Company and Status together...is this kind of design ideal or would your solution be better?

Comment: Given the relationships you depicted in your question between `A`, `B`, and `C`, I'm not sure you could _effectively_ model these associations without assigning a status to a company. It _may_ be possible, but what I've presented will almost certainly provide the behavior you're looking for.

Comment: How would you store different users' status in 1 company? Looks like the status in Company will always be overwritten for different users. (certainly not the behaviour I'm after)

Comment: Hmm... that's a bit complicated. Let me do some research – I'll update my answer when I find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

In your **User.rb** model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :companies
end
```

In your **Company.rb** model:

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

I'm assuming status is an attribute in your company table. With this setup you should be able to do the command you want.

Comment: How can the status be on the company table if the company has many users of different statuses!

Answer (score 0):

I would use the [Rolify Gem](https://github.com/EppO/rolify) to accomplish this.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    rolify
    has_and_belongs_to_many :companies

    def status(company)
        roles = [:manager, :supervisor, :line-level]
        status = []
        roles.each { |role| status << role if self.has_role? role, company }
        return status
    end
end

class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
    resourcify
    has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end
```

This would allow you to do...

```
@company = @user.companies.first
@user.status @company     #=> [:manager] An array assuming they can have many roles.
```

Using this gem allows you to place multiple roles on a single object and scoped to that object.

Comment: I need a pattern of associations that can work with a few different A-B-C scenarios, not just for status or role. This looks like its built specifically for roles...

Comment: What are some example statuses that will be modeled?

Comment: Each user has different Companies enabled or disabled. Each company has different Users enabled or disabled.